# Show two differently hosted angular projects in single angular wrapper UI project

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-ui-router, angular8

What I have?
Two existing angular apps which are hosted on different instances. Both applications use angular 8.

What needs to be done?
Create one angular wrapper project which will (combine) load existing apps as a part of the wrapper project by clicking on the sidebar menu item.

Any lead would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have two distinct applications in the first place.

## Solution 1 - iframe:

the wrapper application should just show iframes for every application in the DOM.

Each application should have its own routing that's passed from wrapper application.

### Pros:

- you don't need to change anything in sub-applications
- it's easy to maintain if applications don't need to share

### Cons:

- it's pretty hard to implement communication/ argument passing between application
- performance, angular is loaded multiple times

## Solution 2 - angular cli workspace and multiple projects

detailed guide about this you can find https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects

With simple google search, I've found this https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

### Pros:

- your applications can share one repo
- your applications should be able to reuse code from each (by making private lib)
- your applications can pass params to each other

### Cons:

- refactoring is required in all applications
- it's difficult to maintain and keep git-flow up to date since one repo can be huge
- the configurations for deployment

I hope this helps you to create a better picture of what needs to be done, unfortunately, I can't provide a step-by-step guide, but as mentioned above simple google search can help you.

Comment: Thank @RockLegend